# I need a word for feature that comes into revelation common to a character or a way someone always presents themself.self

Tags: meaning

What is a word for being revealed in a old tale for example by a stand out feature one has guard down about-like a vestigial tail per example that is about telling or giving account of a distinctive feature one should notice and interpret?

Answer (score 0):

A **distinguishing [mark](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mark)**:

> **1.1** A spot, area, or feature on a person's or animal's body by which they may be identified or recognized.
>
> ‘he was five feet nine, with no distinguishing marks’

Comment: Jason Bassford might well be correct but it's too hard to tell, because of your wording. Could you re-phrase that Question at least twice, for clarity?